# How to split csv files into multiple ones based on certain values of a dataframe (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a data as follows

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GIP1 | .. | .. |
| GIP1 | .. | .. |
| GIP2 | .. | .. |
| GIP2 | .. | .. |
| GIP3 | .. | .. |

I want to split the csv file based on the ID. GIP1 feature csv files as GIP1.csv and GIP2 as GIP2.csv and so on.

Can anyone please help me how to do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can use the loc function in pandas. I am assuming you read your csv in as a pandas df

Now you can write a for loop like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("gips.csv")
features = df.Id.unique()
for f in features:
    df_split = df.loc[df.ID == f]
    df_split.to_csv(f"{f}.csv")
```